# Selecting single element from a long list with hirarchy

Tags: lists, hierarchy, radio-buttons, longlist

I'm creating a wizard where in one of the steps the user needs to select **only one option** from a large list with hierarchy.

The list will have about 30 top level categories.

He can select the top level options or the sub level options.

The first idea was to create something like this: 
A large radio group with hierarchy.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25w0e.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The second option i thought about is with a search box that will do a live search in the options and reduce the list

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBucmr.png)</sup>

Would like to hear you approach on this :)

Thank you.

Comment: How many items in the list? How many categories? I think this will determine the best approach.

It seems strange that it is meaningful to select a whole category (Animals) but not multiple items within that category (Wombats and Badgers).

Comment: The list will have about 30 top level categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if any non-tech user understands how radio buttons works. Possible problem: The user selects various options and does not notice that the previous choice will be deleted.

An easier and more understandable way to handle it, is to use a dropdown menu with filter. The filter works, like yours. I think in this way it is understandable that the user has only one option.

[image: Example for dropdown field]